# How to use Php inside Php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Can someone tell/show me how to use PHP inside PHP.
I'm trying to make the URL of an image change depending on what value is in a MySQL database.
Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. Bear in mind that $idx already has a value from the URL of the page.

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE uname='$idx'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "<img src='' name='comm' width='75px' height='60px' id='mainimage' />";
}
?>
```

How would I make the source value, for the image, come from a different table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd do another SQL query inside the `while` loop. I like how you put it, "Php inside Php", that's pretty much what you do.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $image_query = "SELECT image_url FROM your_table";
  $image_result = mysql_query($image_query);
  $image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_result);

  echo "<img src='" . $image['image_url'] . "' name='comm' width='75px' height='60px' id='mainimage' />";
}
```

Make sure the variable names for your query and result are different from your original query, because you're still using the `$result` variable from the original query each iteration of the loop. So here I've prefixed them with "image_".

Answer (score 7):

You can join data from multiple tables in a single SQL query. See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Example:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name1
JOIN table_name2
ON table_name1.column_name=table_name2.column_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming at a random guess that the other table might be called `accounts`, and `uname` is its primary key, you can do a `JOIN` to grab the data from the both tables in one go. If you can fit what you want to do in a single query that's typically much faster than doing an extra query per row

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query(
        "SELECT comment.*, account.url AS imgurl ".
        "FROM comment JOIN account ON comment.uname=account.uname ".
        "WHERE comment.uname='".mysql_real_escape_string($idx)."'"
    );
?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['imgurl']) ?>" alt="" class="mainimage" />
<?php } ?>
```

Notes:

- you need to escape text you insert into an SQL query, or you've get serious security problems. Use `mysql_real_escape_string`, or let parameterised queries handle it;
- similarly when putting text into an HTML string, `htmlspecialchars` is needed or you've got other (less serious, but still not good) security issues;
- you mustn't use the same `id` on an element more than once (which it will be, in a loop). The same goes for `name` on `<img>`, although there's little reason you'd really ever want to use `img name`;
- `width="75px"` won't work in an attribute as `px`-unit measurements are CSS not HTML. Omit the unit, or, better, set a rule in CSS (`.mainimage { width: 75px; height: 60px; }`) to do them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I make the source value, for the image, come from a different table?

You have to simply ask the different table. You can ask by creating subquery (or join) or create second query inside loop.